# Как реализовать цикл, который будет работать, пока есть строки для ввода

Tags: python

Здравствуйте.

Задачка  по [этой](http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/dicts/problems/sales/) ссылке.

> Условие
>
> Дана база данных о продажах некоторого интернет-магазина. Каждая строка входного файла представляет собой запись вида Покупатель товар
>   количество, где Покупатель — имя покупателя (строка без пробелов),
>   товар — название товара (строка без пробелов), количество — количество
>   приобретенных единиц товара.
>
> Создайте список всех покупателей, а для каждого покупателя подсчитайте количество приобретенных им единиц каждого вида товаров.
>   Список покупателей, а также список товаров для каждого покупателя
>   нужно выводить в лексикографическом порядке.

Задачу я решил, только не знаю как реализировать цикл, который будет работать, пока есть строки для ввода. Так как надо написать код для варианта, когда мы не знаем сколько точно будет введено строк.

Мое решение:

```
dic = {}
while True: #это неверно
    a = input().split(' ')
    if not a[0] in dic:
        dic[a[0]] = {a[1]:a[2]} 
    else:
        if not a[1] in dic[a[0]].keys():
            dic[a[0]].update({a[1]:a[2]} )
        else:
            dic[a[0]][a[1]]=int(dic[a[0]][a[1]]) + int(a[2])

for x in sorted(dic.keys()):
    print(x +':')
    for y in sorted(dic[x].keys()):
        print (y, dic[x][y])
```

Comment: Задачка http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/dicts/problems/sales/

Comment: Спасибо, обновлено

Answer (score 2):

Читать данные в вашем случае нужно немного иначе.

Сделайте такой импорт

```
from sys import stdin
```

Так вы получите доступ к стандартному потоку ввода.

Пройтись в цикле по всем строкам можно таким образом:

```
for i in stdin:
    //
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил таким образом:

```
def Example(Path_File):
    with open(Path_File, 'r') as file: # Открываем файл
        lines = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines() if line != '\n'] # Делаем список из строк файла
        result = dict() # Делаем пустой словарь, тут будет результат
        for i in lines: # Проходим по списку строк который сделали
            time_var = i.split() # Разбиваем строку i на список из 3 элементов, а именно 
                                 # 1 элементом будет Имя, 2 элементом - Товар, 3 элементом - Кол-во
            if time_var[0] not in result.keys():
                # Проверяем есть ли ключ с менем time_var[0] (Там имя покупателя) в нашем словаре
                result[time_var[0]] = {time_var[1]: int(time_var[2])} # Добавляем его
            else: # В противном случае
                if time_var[1] in result[time_var[0]]: # Если у покупателя есть такой товар
                    result[time_var[0]][time_var[1]] += int(time_var[2]) # Увеличиваем кол-во этого товара
                else: # В противном случае
                    result[time_var[0]].update({time_var[1]: int(time_var[2])}) # Добавляем ему этот товар
    return result # Возвращаем результат
```

Использование:

```
print(Example(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\bd_file.txt'))
```

В `bd_file.txt` я поместил следующее:

```
Ivanov paper 10
Petrov pens 5
Ivanov marker 3
Ivanov paper 7
Petrov envelope 20
Ivanov envelope 5
```

Результат:

```
{
    'Ivanov': {
        'paper': 17,
        'marker': 3,
        'envelope': 5
    },
    'Petrov': {
        'pens': 5,
        'envelope': 20
    }
}
```

Comment: Alban, спасибо за ответ, есть только один минус - на сайте, котором размещена задачка, нельзя работать с текст документами :)

Comment: @Grzegorzg LOL, я не прочел что вы хотите до конца :), подумал что нужно решение, черт)

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу благодаря совету Кирилла Малышева использовать sys.stdin, вот мой код:

```
from sys import stdin
# Используются вложенные в друг друга словари
# Словарь покупателей (sales). Ключ = имя покупателя, значение = словарь покупок
# Словарь покупок. Ключ = название предмета, значение - количесвтво
sales = {}
for line in stdin.readlines():
    person, product, amount = line.split()
    amount = int(amount)
    if sales.get(person) == None:
        sales[person] = {}
    sales[person][product] = sales[person].get(product,0) + amount
# Сортируем покупки и преобразуем в список используя генератор списков
sales = [(s, sorted([(j, sales[s][j]) for j in sales[s]])) for s in sales]
# Выводим
for person in sorted(sales):
    name, products = person[0], person[1]
    print(name, end=":\n")
    for p in products:
        print(*p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы читать ввод построчно, пока он не закончится, можно использовать `sys.stdin` файловый объект. Любое API, которое файл ожидает, примет этот объект (детали могут зависеть, чему в вашем окружении `sys.stdin` присвоен -- это может не "настоящий" файл). К примеру, `sys.stdin` можно передать в `pandas.read_table()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pandas as pd  # $ pip install pandas

df = pd.read_table(sys.stdin, delim_whitespace=True,
                   names=['buyer', 'product', 'amount'])
print(df.groupby(['buyer', 'product']).sum())
```

Для примера ввода из [ответа @Alban](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657151/23044), этот код выводит:

```
$ python . <input.txt
                 amount
buyer  product         
Ivanov envelope       5
       marker         3
       paper         17
Petrov envelope      20
       pens           5
```

Файлы в Питоне являются итераторами над строками, поэтому их можно в for-цикл как есть передать `for line in sys.stdin:`. Чтобы принимать ввод как из стандартного ввода так и из файлов, указанных в командной строчке, можно `fileinput.input()` использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
for line in fileinput.input():
    buyer, product, amount = line.split()
    counter[buyer, product] += int(amount)
```

Что на том же вводе приводит к:

```
Counter({('Petrov', 'envelope'): 20,
         ('Ivanov', 'paper'): 17,
         ('Petrov', 'pens'): 5,
         ('Ivanov', 'envelope'): 5,
         ('Ivanov', 'marker'): 3})
```

Чтобы напечатать в желаемом отсортированном виде:

```
last_buyer = None
for (buyer, product), amount in sorted(counter.items()):
    if last_buyer != buyer:  # new buyer
        print(buyer, end=' ')
        last_buyer = buyer
    else:
        print(' ' * len(buyer), end=' ')
    print(product, amount)
```

Результат:

```
Ivanov envelope 5
       marker 3
       paper 17
Petrov envelope 20
       pens 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from sys import stdin

clients = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for line in stdin.readlines():
    client, thing, value = line.split()
    clients[client][thing] += int(value)

for client in sorted(clients):
    print(client + ':')
    for thing in sorted(clients[client]):
        print(thing, clients[client][thing])
```