# Остановить цикл, принимающий input по окончанию ввода

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, input

В задаче для начинающих столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Цикл должен принимать неопределенное количество строк через input. После считывания всех строк и выполнения цикла нужно вывести кое-какие данные.
`for i in range()` не подойдет. Пробую цикл `while True`. Когда input'ы заканчиваются, выдаёт `EOFerror`. Никаких условий на остановку цикла в вводимых данных нет. Как же оформить или остановить цикл?

Comment: Ловить EOFerror и останавливать цикл

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `fileinput`:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    # ваш код
```

Comment: Подошло бы, если бы в этой задачке можно было онлайн загрузить файл с данными.

Comment: @user276645 вы сперва код попробуйте. fileinput может и из стандартного ввода читать. Если не хотите дополнительно файлы поддерживать, то просто `for line in sys.stdin: ..` чтобы построчно из стандартного ввода читать.

Comment: Когда вы используете пустой список параметров в методе `fileinput.input()`, строки будут читаться из стандартного ввода.

Comment: 'ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)'
После того, как ввожу строки с данными по одному, жму Enter, вводится пустая строка.

Comment: Вместо пустой строки закончите ввод `Ctrl`+`D`.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ на свой вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657131/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8-python)

```
from sys import stdin
for i in stdin.readlines():
```